# Where does print statements logged when the python code is started during the bootup

Tags: 16.04, boot, systemd, python-2.7

I wrote a .service(systemd) to start a python script during the boot up. There service is working fine and is trying to execute the python script. In order to debug python script i placed few print statements to see how far the python code is reached to and got failed. But not sure where these print statements are printed/ logged.

I tried to look into

```
systemctl status xyz.service
journalctl -u xyz.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588421/how-to-log-to-journald-systemd-via-python) if you need to log from python script.

```
import logging
from systemd.journal import JournalHandler

log = logging.getLogger('demo')
log.addHandler(JournalHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.info("sent to journal")
```

If you need to log from native logging via bash use `systemd-cat`.

Ex: `echo 'hello' | systemd-cat` then view `journalctl`